# How can I set up a code to look up the word of the Front field in Anki?

Tags: anki

How can I set up a code to look up the word of the `Front field` in Example field and change the color of them for all words of the deck?

[image: See image here]

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped every field in a `<div>`, so it should be relatively simple to add some `color` to the text using the `style` attribute.

```html
<p>Add a <code>style</code> attribute to the
<div style="color: red;">text that you want to be red.</div>
<p><br />
<p>If one already exists, append the <code>color</code>
<div style="font-size: xx-large; color: blue;">to it.</div>
```

Because you're changing the style for the card type, this should be applied to all cards of this type.